# Is django-lazysignup allow_lazy_user decorator calling the wrapped view twice?

Tags: django, decorator, lazy-registration

I'm using ["django-lazysignup 0.8"](https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup) with Django 1.3.

When I do this:

## The view

```
@allow_lazy_user
def page_edit(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    if is_lazy_user(request.user):
        b2 = Page.objects.create(user=request.user)
        print request.user.username
        return render_to_response('page_editor.html',{'page':b2})
```

the console output shows that the view seems to be called twice (b2 called twice and creates the Page object twice, and the print statment prints twice)

Here is the output screen :

## Output:

```
7707089a583a424caf0face130cb20  # this is the reult of  print request.user.username 
[12/Mar/2012 15:02:45] "GET /edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8368
7707089a583a424caf0face130cb20
[12/Mar/2012 15:02:46] "GET /edit/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8368
```

I don't need this to happen, the view should be called once and create one Page object. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to Django-lazysignup.

If you look at the url for the second request:

```
/edit/images/favicon.ico
```

That looks to me like your browser trying to load the favicon for your website. That suggests you've used a relative path `images/favicon.ico` instead of an absolute path `/images/favicon.ico`.

It doesn't seem quite right that the favicon url has called the `page_edit` view. This suggests your url pattern is missing a `$` to denote the end of string. You should change it to something like:

```
url('^edit/$', 'page_edit'),
```